# jQuery Syntax Issue - Blur + Focus Problems

Tags: jquery

I'm using the following code to show and hide a label on a text field when someone enters text in the box.

What I'm attempting to do is when you click on the box the text disappears, and if you don't enter text, the label reappears. Any idea what i'm doing wrong?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("input:text").focus(function () {
            if ($(this).val == "Name/Email:") {
                $(this).val("");    
            };  
        });

        $("input:text").blur(function () {
            if ($(this).val == "") {
                $(this).val("Name/Email:"); 
            };
        });
    });
</script>

<input id="page4-input1" type="text" value="Name/Email:"  />
<input id="page4-input2" type="text" value="Name/Email:" />
<input id="page4-input3" type="text" value="Name/Email:" />
<input id="page4-input4" type="text" value="Name/Email:" />
<input id="page4-input5" type="text" value="Name/Email:" />
```

Comment: When clicking on the input boxes, nothing occurs and the label stays in the box

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(this).val
```

should instead be:

```
$(this).val()
```

since it is a method (and not a property).

[**Your code, fixed.**](http://jsfiddle.net/karim79/5C9MC/)

Also, consider using the ['placeholder' attribute](http://davidwalsh.name/html5-placeholder) and falling back to JavaScript in browsers which do not support it.

Comment: Perfect, i shall have to remember that for next time! Ill give you the accepted answer when i can (timer and all).

Answer (score 0):

You missed the brackets after `val` when performing the comparison:

```
$("input:text").focus(function () {
    if ($(this).val() == "Name/Email:") {
        $(this).val("");    
    };  
});

$("input:text").blur(function () {
    if ($(this).val() == "") {
        $(this).val("Name/Email:"); 
    };
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/seFND/1/)